# How to control motor (1.5 V at about 0.5 A) with Particle Photon using optocouplers and transistors?

Tags: transistors, opto-isolator

I’m trying to control a motor that runs at 1.5v at ~0.5A using a Particle Photon. I’m powering the Photon over USB (for now, at least) and the motor with a AA battery. I’ve tried designs based off [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-13-dc-motors/breadboard-layout) schematic (modified to power the motor with the battery) but ended up with unacceptable noise in a separate circuit connected to the Photon. I’ve also tried [this](https://learnabout-electronics.org/Semiconductors/opto_52.php) design without success. I’m a total noob at this stuff so any help would be appreciated.

I have an inexhaustible supply of resistors, a variety pack of transistors and diodes, some small capacitors, and PC817 optocouplers at my disposal (along with some other misc. components).

[I’ve read this but most of it went over my head.](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/optocoupler-circuits)

Comment: what's a particle photon?

Comment: @jsotola I think it’s optocoupler

Comment: It's not an optocoupler. Particle Photon is a IoT board with WiFi connectivity and STM32 microcontroller.

Comment: @Ezra, in English we use capital letters for proper nouns including names and brand names. This would make it clear that you are using a Particle Photon rather than a particle photon. Capitals matter! Can you [edit] the question title and your post to fix that?

Comment: @Transistor I’m a native english speaker, just on my phone and forgot to double check that . Thanks for the catch!

Comment: You scored only 2 out of 4! I fixed the others.

Answer (score 0):

fortunately the noise of a motor with these specs is easy to control.
the figure 5.2.5 in the second link, works fine. but I assume you have connected both grounds together. it should be connected like this :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5SW5i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

this way, there is no physical connection between motor control and logic circuits. but there are some notes:

- a tiny relay would work without much hassle.
- the transistor should withstand at least 1amps for a safe margin.

Comment: Just to double check- this should work with a PC817? I realized I forgot to include the exact part I have in my question.

Comment: @Ezra yes it works with PC817 and many other transistor output opto-isolators.